# Using accelerometer for animation and output?

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer

i'm new to xcode and objective c, so be indulgent :)

i wrote an app where i can move a small ball over the display using the accelerometer.

in addition i want to output the accelerometer data on the display.

the problem is, when i want to output the data the ball won't move.

thanks for help!

```
xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x: %f.02", acceleration.x];
yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"y: %f.02", acceleration.y];
zLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"z: %f.02", acceleration.z];
```

Here's the initializing code:

```
UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer]; //Share reference 
accel.delegate = self;
accel.updateInterval = 1.0f / 60.0f;
```

Comment: please post the ball moving code also or the accelerometer initializing code.

Answer (score 0):

That may be because you trying to both the tasks on main thread which is not possible simultaneously.

I think you can use Core animation (which uses its own thread to perform its operations) to move object instead of directly changing frame of the object (which requires main thread).